# No operator "*" matches these operands... operand types are: const Vec2 * float

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I get error "`Error (active)    E0349   no operator "*" matches these operands... operand types are: const Vec2 * float`" in the function Project. I have defined operator * and it seems like the parameters match... I don't see where I did wrong..

```
class Vec2
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;

    Vec2 operator*(const float &right) {
        Vec2 result;
        result.x = x * right;
        result.y = y * right;
        return result;
    }    

    float MagnitudeSq() const
    {
        return sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    float DistanceSq(const Vec2& v2)
    {
        return pow((v2.x - x), 2) + pow((v2.y - y), 2);
    }

    float Dot(const Vec2& v2)
    {
        return x*v2.x + y*v2.y;
    }

    Vec2 Project(const Vec2& v2)
    {
        *this = v2 * std::fmax(0, std::fmin(1, (*this).Dot(v2) / this->MagnitudeSq()));
    }
};
```

Comment: Off-topic:  Performing `x * x` is more efficient than `pow(x, 2)`.

Comment: BTW, class methods and members don't require using the `this` pointer.  For example, you can call `Dot` directly as well as `MagnitudeSq`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, On the other hand, [the compiler is pretty good at optimizing](https://godbolt.org/g/PBnZaN).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare the `operator *` of `vec2` as acting on a `const` object.

```
Vec2 operator*(const float &right) const { 
//                                ^^^^^^
```

This is because in the method `Vec2 Project(const Vec2& v2)` you are using the operator* on `v2` which you have declared const in the prototype.

Answer (score 4):

change  the Line

```
Vec2 operator*(const float &right) {
```

to

```
Vec2 operator*(const float &right) const {
```

and it should work.

You are trying to perform a non const member function on a const object right now.